# Android Studio does not recognise layout in flavour

Tags: android-studio, layout, resources

After update to AS4 I started to have very strange issues with existing project which was working just fine in AS3.6.

See the screenshot:

[image: Android Studio 4 does not recognise layouts in flavour]
Just to avoid common overloading by common advices:

- I tried to "Invalidate Caches & Restart"
- I tried to "delete all ".idea" and ".gradle" and "build" folders and reimport the project (and subsequent "Invalidate Caches & Restart" again)
- I checked the "Project Structure" dialog, after the (re-)import of the project from Gradle - the build variants, including flavours seem to be OK
- I double checked all my dependencies are at the latest available version
- I double checked my Gradle (6.1.1) and Android Gradle Plugin (4.0.0) are also at the latest version
- I am on MAC, so no influence by the virus called Microshit Willows

**Note**: The project builds FINE and installs into the phone also FINE - the problem is only that the Android Studio 4 IDE appears to be buggy (again and again, Google probably does not have any validation of their products).

**Note**: According to the icon in the "Project" pane, it seems that AS does understand that "res" is a resource folder:

[image: AS4 seems to recognise the res folder in a flavour]

**Note**: Subsequently, some features in the Java editor are not working properly as well: The R.layout. is not recognised, the IDs of views in the layout are also not recognised...

**Does anyone know how to get out of this crazy situation?**

Comment: Same here, not finding solution yet